# How to define Singleton in TypeScript

Tags: singleton, typescript

What is the best and most convenient way to implement a Singleton pattern for a class in TypeScript? (Both with and without lazy initialisation).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Singleton classes in TypeScript are generally an anti-pattern. You can simply use [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) instead.

#### Useless singleton pattern

```
class Singleton {
    /* ... lots of singleton logic ... */
    public someMethod() { ... }
}

// Using
var x = Singleton.getInstance();
x.someMethod();
```

#### Namespace equivalent

```
export namespace Singleton {
    export function someMethod() { ... }
}
// Usage
import { SingletonInstance } from "path/to/Singleton";

SingletonInstance.someMethod();
var x = SingletonInstance; // If you need to alias it for some reason
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `namespace` rather than `module`? We can export modules.

Comment: `namespace` and `module` mean exactly the same thing

Comment: Since Typescript 1.5 it's split namespaces and modules slightly - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md - A note about terminology: It's important to note that in TypeScript 1.5, the nomenclature has changed. "Internal modules" are now "namespaces". "External modules" are now simply "modules", as to align with ECMAScript 2015's terminology, (namely that module X { is equivalent to the now-preferred namespace X {).

Comment: Consider that the class is the core concept of organizing state and behavior in object oriented languages and that this concept is offered by Typescript as it extends javascript to give us some of the concepts we find useful for organizing our code but are missing in javascript. In all other languages we use the structure of the class if we want a singleton, this is the de facto norm. Even if the singleton-pattern in typescript might be successfully implemented by a completely different structural concept, the namespace, is this really worth the increased conceptual complexity and ambiguity?

Comment: it would be nice to now why is the singleton is considered an anti pattern? consider this approach http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-singleton-pattern/

Comment: I'd like to know why Singletons in TypeScript are considered an anti-pattern too. And also if it doesn't have any constructor parameters why not `export default new Singleton()`?

Comment: He said "singleton *classes*" are considered an anti-pattern, not "singletons". I suppose that it makes sense when you consider that a class is generally meant for reusing the code in that class across multiple instances of that class.

Comment: The namespace solution looks more like a static class, not a singleton

Comment: It behaves the same. In C#, you can't pass a static class around as if it were a value (i.e. as if it were an instance of a singleton class), which limits its usefulness. In TypeScript, you *can* pass a namespace around like an instance. That's why you don't need singleton classes.

Comment: What about when you want a getter property on your singleton?

Comment: A limitation of using a namespace as a singleton is that it cannot (to my knowledge) implement an interface.  Would you agree with this @ryan

Comment: I added the ´export´ on the namespace declaration and the ´import´ that is also needed

Comment: The link from codebelt.com is broken. I think this is the actual link: https://codebelt.github.io/blog/typescript/typescript-singleton-pattern/

Comment: As far as I can tell it is now namespaces which are the antipattern. See this eslint rule: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v2.34.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md

Comment: The code demonstrates importing a function from a namespace which is not demonstrating the GoF Singleton pattern.  The advantage of the Singleton pattern is the singleton has a state and functions that are in a globally shared object instance.

Answer (score 284):

Since TS 2.0, we have the ability to define [visibility modifiers on constructors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#private-and-protected-constructors), so now we can do singletons in TypeScript just like we are used to from other languages.

Example given:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static _instance: MyClass;

    private constructor()
    {
        //...
    }

    public static get Instance()
    {
        // Do you need arguments? Make it a regular static method instead.
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
    }
}

const myClassInstance = MyClass.Instance;
```

---

Thank you @Drenai for pointing out that if you write code using the raw compiled javascript you will not have protection against multiple instantiation, as the constraints of TS disappears and the constructor won't be hidden.

Comment: the constructor could be private?

Comment: @Expertwannabe Not in the current version of TypeScript, but it is planned for version 2.0.

Comment: @Expertwannabe This is now available in TS 2.0: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#private-and-protected-constructors

Comment: Is there a reason that doing the following with the suggested implementation still creates multiple instances when importing the module:


export default MyClass.Instance;

Comment: fyi, the reason for the multiple instances was the node module resolution getting in the way.  Thus, if you are creating a singleton in node make sure that that's considered.  I ended up creating a node_modules folder under my src directory and putting the singleton in there.

Comment: Nice use of a getter!

Comment: I like this pattern. This does not seem to work in IE8 unfortunately, even when your TS targets ES5.

Comment: @Alex yes the get compiles down to a line of code using `Object.defineProperty` this has known issues in IE8. Possible workarounds  are given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819693/working-around-ie8s-broken-object-defineproperty-implementation . These include the use of a small polyfill file.

Comment: @Alex I have since removed the `get` from the code and invoked `instance()` as a function and this compiles into code that IE8 is fine with :) This seems like a good enough solution for me. Thanks for the above answer!

Comment: Another possibility is to do `private static readonly instance = new MyClass();`. This is slightly different because it will create an instance of the class whether one is requested or not, but otherwise, it's a pretty clean solution.

Comment: This is the right approach so far as the current version of TypeScript

Comment: @KimchiMan If the project is ever used in a non-typescript environment e.g. imported into a JS project, the class will have no protection against further instantiation. It works in a pure TS environment only, but not for JS library development

Comment: @Alex how to make this a Singleton with need config arguments to be "initialised"?

Comment: @lony Just make _Instance_ a normal static method (remove 'get') that takes the arguments needed from where you pass those to the constructor that also takes the arguments needed.

Comment: How to convert this to a (abstract) base class?

Comment: How would you mock this with Jest?

Comment: use of `this._instance` in getter is inappropriate  it need to change since its a static on line 1 of the answer 

OR even better copied directly from typescriptlang.org 

`
 class Singleton {
  private static instance: Singleton;
  private constructor() {}
  static getInstance() {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return Singleton.instance;
  }
}
let e = new Singleton(); // Error: constructor of 'Singleton' is private.
let v = Singleton.getInstance(); 
`

Comment: @PankajAvhad Using this within a static method refers to the static class, not to an instance. I guess that was what you though was wrong?

Answer (score 57):

The best way I have found is:

```
class SingletonClass {

    private static _instance:SingletonClass = new SingletonClass();

    private _score:number = 0;

    constructor() {
        if(SingletonClass._instance){
            throw new Error("Error: Instantiation failed: Use SingletonClass.getInstance() instead of new.");
        }
        SingletonClass._instance = this;
    }

    public static getInstance():SingletonClass
    {
        return SingletonClass._instance;
    }

    public setScore(value:number):void
    {
        this._score = value;
    }

    public getScore():number
    {
        return this._score;
    }

    public addPoints(value:number):void
    {
        this._score += value;
    }

    public removePoints(value:number):void
    {
        this._score -= value;
    }

}
```

Here is how you use it:

```
var scoreManager = SingletonClass.getInstance();
scoreManager.setScore(10);
scoreManager.addPoints(1);
scoreManager.removePoints(2);
console.log( scoreManager.getScore() );
```

https://codebelt.github.io/blog/typescript/typescript-singleton-pattern/

Comment: Why not make the constructor private?

Comment: I think the post predates the ability to have private constructors in TS. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2341

Comment: The link is broken. I think this is the actual link: https://codebelt.github.io/blog/typescript/typescript-singleton-pattern/

Comment: It's better place "new SingletonClass()" in method "getInstance", otherwise constructor will excute at the location of import this class which we don't expect that happens in some situation.

Answer (score 34):

The following approach creates a Singleton class that can be used exacly like a conventional class:

```
class Singleton {
    private static instance: Singleton;
    //Assign "new Singleton()" here to avoid lazy initialisation

    constructor() {
        if (Singleton.instance) {
            return Singleton.instance;
        }

        this. member = 0;
        Singleton.instance = this;
    }

    member: number;
}
```

Each `new Singleton()` operation will return the same instance. This can however be unexpected by the user.

The following example is more transparent to the user but requires a different usage:

```
class Singleton {
    private static instance: Singleton;
    //Assign "new Singleton()" here to avoid lazy initialisation

    constructor() {
        if (Singleton.instance) {
            throw new Error("Error - use Singleton.getInstance()");
        }
        this.member = 0;
    }

    static getInstance(): Singleton {
        Singleton.instance = Singleton.instance || new Singleton();
        return Singleton.instance;
    }

    member: number;
}
```

Usage: `var obj = Singleton.getInstance();`

Comment: This is the way it should be implemented. If there's 1 thing I disagree with The Gang of Four on -- and it's probably *only* 1 -- its The Singleton Pattern. Perhaps, C/++ impedes one from designing it this way. But if you ask me, client code should not know or care if its a Singleton. Clients should still implement `new Class(...)` syntax.

Comment: Disagree with Cody a new instance must be a new instance, otherwise devs will do wrong assumptions.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with the above statement (Juan). getInstance() here has some side effects (it creates a new object) when its name suggests it shouldn't at all (getXXX). I believe it's even worst.

Comment: You can use private constructors in typescript.

Comment: @HakanDemir not in 2015 :P

Answer (score 30):

I am surprised not to see the following pattern here, which actually looks very simple.

```
// shout.ts
class ShoutSingleton {
  helloWorld() { return 'hi'; }
}

export let Shout = new ShoutSingleton();
```

Usage

```
import { Shout } from './shout';
Shout.helloWorld();
```

Comment: I got the following error message:

Exported variable 'Shout' has or is using private name 'ShoutSingleton '.

Comment: You have to export the class 'ShoutSingleton' too, and the error disappear.

Comment: Right, I am surprised as well. Why even bother with the class though? Singletons are supposed to hide their internal workings. Why not just export function helloWorld?

Comment: see this github issue for more info: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307

Comment: Guess nothing is stopping users from just creating a new `Shout` class though

Comment: *I'm* a little surprised not to see it, too -- and this is a great solution  -- but the better implementation (IMO) comes from @maja's answer. See my comment therein for an explanation why.

Comment: I am not sure either why there are not more samples using a bare const export. To fix the private name thing, best is to use s public interface. Exporting just the inner function works ln this example as is pure, but imagine you have a stateful singleton.

Comment: I do not need to export `ShoutSingleton` in typescript 4.7.2 . This is the best solution imo.

Comment: @dalore Is not being exported so that stops users from creating a new instance, if you mean a new class with the same name the other answers here don't help with that either.

Comment: The problem with this solution `export let Shout = new ShoutSingleton();` is that it's not the Singleton pattern because it doesn't fulfill the Singleton's objective of 'Ensuring that a class has only one instance.' This is because every time you import it, you create new instances instead of reusing the same one.
In short, for it to be a Singleton, you would need to ensure that the same instance is always returned, not a new one.
This is resolved by adding 'Lazy Initialization.'

Answer (score 15):

Add the following 6 lines to any class to make it "Singleton".

```
class MySingleton
{
    private constructor(){ /* ... */}
    private static _instance: MySingleton;
    public static getInstance(): MySingleton
    {
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
    };
}
```

[Test example:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20class%20MySingleton%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20constructor()%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%09private%20static%20_instance%3AMySingleton%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09public%20static%20getInstance()%3AMySingleton%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09return%20this._instance%7C%7C(this._instance%20%3D%20new%20this())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20a%3A%20MySingleton%20%3D%20MySingleton.getInstance()%3B%0Aconst%20b%3A%20MySingleton%20%3D%20MySingleton.getInstance()%3B%0A%0Aalert%20(a%20%3D%3D%3D%20b)%0A)

```
var test = MySingleton.getInstance(); // will create the first instance
var test2 = MySingleton.getInstance(); // will return the first instance
alert(test === test2); // true
```

[Edit]: Use Alex answer if you prefer to get the instance through a property rather a method.

[Edit 2]: Bonus: if you want to generate a singleton from your existing class **in one line**, you can use this class builder:

```js
function AsSingleton<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(Aclass: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) {
  return class extends Aclass {
    static #instance: InstanceType<T>;
    public static getInstance(): InstanceType<T> {
      if (!this.#instance) {
        this.#instance = new Aclass(...args);
      }
      return this.#instance;
    }
  } as Omit<T,"new"> & {getInstance:()=>InstanceType<T>};
}
```

[Check this snippet for an example (even more advanced)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQM4GUZgOYBsCmUCAPACqL4AeU+YAJqomPgO6IAUAdNwIYBO2VAC5EPMAE8A2gF0AlIgC8APlESl7ZBFw9UwxKQA0ibp36CRAYQSoofENDh8ACvx4BbQvj6oyS+QG8AKERECGsoREwcAiIkBRCtHUYqGnpGTW1dRCCQkJseWAhEAGIsfMh8AH4RAEkwcoh8UnEAB3xfAG5g3IB6ACo+7ty+xAAZHgAvcURsQkQoAAt8RHzCxDKoMUahkL6enZaQACNcGCLVs5nCOob8dlla+s2K5rbfbJ2QmGAOAEJFmCoTilJ5bfABT65AFAkG3RRMVgoRK6Li8ASoWRdXK5AC+kL4hBAfCQ0OBGzBvyxuJ2O36g2xiBGACV8AQdMtFstyRUOG44DZEHAfpz5jAPIhxHAQIgWAgAOQRZj4OjzBaA2SfPYHY6nc6bNZafD8G7PRr3EQANzgMBVOQZpNhpuW8XAdHwwCwyqpITxPqpPR6iDcPAA1hylqFwnYHHxEC0+DALQV8N0CVAiUgonhCAhRIwAPJuGBQYhQVr4IWRLDZ2IGABEzBYdaUgTxgTpwRGmFwuGmyNQnf2-cQAFlxBZMow7WEntGiHx2PHE8nRLMRGAQG4jl4Am2QocTpcjjA+Is6DxxPc7SFSTxZgBqe9UvdxnWXJdgKDIWZXnYz1BwAQnC4HA2DsLesyYt0L4XOcF4ABKsiBv7YjwBCnuwdaIT2cB1hqPqtoEgT-hEyATkkWYxLm8RoJROZgOwY7kboRgAIyYogAahASK48Cs1ZUUgwB8HAbgSlKsb9kYkrSkqKpEHGIkWja4bLG6wA8CAuARCRc6OHKjBmJutBQIw7DfKo4gaoEZGTnRsScLMUAmmC9ycB+X4-hxAasTZzEYAJ9GOdcoIVG5Hnfnc3k9L5fl2YFDlOS5YWyJwx6ngs56XtF6yQASHifqqyx3imtkUQlCDBc5oVmqlEVeR0nGBgATERZW6PZlWGsaNVRV07UBdEQVJb14UJp+kX3I1PlGNuECaagXJQAZogImw3LbHF5VDQ5qAIUhcBTU1oRoacOCrbBQb4FuXiCj8TGTjKjghgOxHhPM8KNig-mdQx7HTYGADqyzzWAYBwBEG2qaEj10Ce+DQL2iAgKg1ZFYgDasHWgptHwBSOEAA)

usage: `const AClassSingleton = AsSingleton(AClass);`

Comment: What happens when I do  `new MySingleton()` , say 5 times? does your code reserve a single instance?

Comment: you should never use "new": as Alex wrote, the constructor should be "private", preventing to do "new MySingleton()". The right usage is to get an instance using MySingleton.getInstance(). AKAIK no constructor (like in my example) = a public empty constructor

Comment: "you should never use "new" - exactly my point:". But how does your implementation prevent me from doing so? I do not see anywhere where you have a private constructor in your class?

Comment: @HlawulekaMAS I did not… I therefore I edited the answer, note that a private constructor was not possible before TS 2.0 (i.e. at the time I wrote the answer first)

Comment: "i.e. at the time I wrote the answer first" - Makes sense. Cool.

Answer (score 8):

My solution for it:

```js
export default class Singleton {
    private static _instance: Singleton = new Singleton();

    constructor() {
        if (Singleton._instance)
            throw new Error("Use Singleton.instance");
        Singleton._instance = this;
    }

    static get instance() {
        return Singleton._instance;
    }
}
```

### 2021 update

Now constructor can be private

```js
export default class Singleton {
    private static _instance?: Singleton;

    private constructor() {
        if (Singleton._instance)
            throw new Error("Use Singleton.instance instead of new.");
        Singleton._instance = this;
    }

    static get instance() {
        return Singleton._instance ?? (Singleton._instance = new Singleton());
    }
}
```

[Test in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCWA7A5iApgFwPaOgbwChpjoAHAJ3gDcwM1oINb5hoB9JRsRYNAfgBccJKkw4A3ASIkK1WvWA5G5AK7Bs5ABQBKfNJIl4AM2iaEKdNkQA6Doi4802-QdcYAFuSwB3aIjS+AKLkXloARACqEPTmolbWnEyO0IloYAAm0Fgm-t7WYdqSriSxlji2idy80AC80B7wEEUkAL5SBlwYLNDImCn2Sbw6esXE5Jgq5LilYjZ2DtV8fKYz8fOD9HW5whazOoUubW0EAPQn0AC0V9AAKoGwN5dXzy+vb+8fr1KW0ONGAIK1HZxcqVRwEH5-ABCQNWoIGVTQUkU9iw6GsICwyE0YUaDBEZUQAjCABpfmgAbUanVoc4CEA)

Comment: In the constructor, instead of the exception you can `return Modal._instance`. This way, if you `new` that class, you get the existing object, not a new one.

Answer (score 7):

You can use class expressions for this (as of 1.6 I believe).

```
var x = new (class {
    /* ... lots of singleton logic ... */
    public someMethod() { ... }
})();
```

or with the name if your class needs to access its type internally

```
var x = new (class Singleton {
    /* ... lots of singleton logic ... */
    public someMethod(): Singleton { ... }
})();
```

Another option is to use a local class inside of your singleton using some static members

```
class Singleton {

    private static _instance;
    public static get instance() {

        class InternalSingleton {
            someMethod() { }

            //more singleton logic
        }

        if(!Singleton._instance) {
            Singleton._instance = new InternalSingleton();
        }

        return <InternalSingleton>Singleton._instance;
    }
}

var x = Singleton.instance;
x.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 7):

i think maybe use generics be batter

```
class Singleton<T>{
    public static Instance<T>(c: {new(): T; }) : T{
        if (this._instance == null){
            this._instance = new c();
        }
        return this._instance;
    }

    private static _instance = null;
}
```

how to use

step1

```
class MapManager extends Singleton<MapManager>{
     //do something
     public init():void{ //do }
}
```

step2

```
    MapManager.Instance(MapManager).init();
```

Comment: For Typescript 3.0 and above, you can use type 'unknown' for the return type of `static Instance` method and the type of `_instance`, then use like `MapManager.Instance(MapManager) as MapManager`. This could eliminate the type mismatch error of eslint.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of the function **Object.Freeze()**. Its simple and easy:

```
class Singleton {

  instance: any = null;
  data: any = {} // store data in here

  constructor() {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = this;
    }
    return this.instance
  }
}

const singleton: Singleton = new Singleton();
Object.freeze(singleton);

export default singleton;
```

Comment: Kenny, good point on freeze(), but two notes: (1) after you freeze(singleton), you still can modify singleton.data.. you can't add other attribute (like data2), but point is that freeze() is not deep freeze :)  and (2) your class Singleton allows to create more than one instance  (example obj1 = new Singleton(); obj2 = new Singleton();), so your Singleton is not Singleton : )

Comment: If you import the Singleton Class in other files you will always get the same instance and the data in 'data' will be consistent between all other imports. That's for me a singleton. The freeze in making sure that the exported Singleton instance is only created once.

Comment: Kenny, (1) if you import your class in other files you won't get instance. By import you're simply bringing class definition in scope so you can create new instances. Then you can create >1 instances of the given class be it in one file or multiple files, which defies the whole purpose of singleton idea. (2) From docs: The Object.freeze() method freezes an object. A frozen object can no longer be changed; freezing an object prevents new properties from being added to it. (end of quote) Which means freeze() does not stop you from creating multiple objects.

Comment: True, but in this case it will, because the exported member is already an instance. And the instance keeps the data. If you put an export on the class as well, your are right and you could create multiple instances.

Comment: @kenny if you know you're going to export an instance, why bother with the `if (!this.instance)` in the constructor?  Is that just an extra precaution in case you created multiple instances before the export?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a new version of this that the Typescript compiler is totally okay with, and I think is better because it doesn't require calling a `getInstance()` method constantly.

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';

export class Singleton {
  // Define your props here
  private _express: Application = express();
  private static _instance: Singleton;

  constructor() {
    if (Singleton._instance) {
      return Singleton._instance;
    }

    // You don't have an instance, so continue

    // Remember, to set the _instance property
    Singleton._instance = this;
  }
}
```

This does come with a different drawback. If your `Singleton` does have any properties, then the Typescript compiler will throw a fit unless you initialize them with a value. That's why I included an `_express` property in my example class because unless you initialize it with a value, even if you assign it later in the constructor, Typescript will think it hasn't been defined. This could be fixed by disabling strict mode, but I prefer not to if possible. There is also another downside to this method I should point out, because the constructor is actually getting called, each time it does another instance is technically created, but not accessible. This could, in theory, cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

After implementing a classic pattern like

```js
class Singleton {
  private instance: Singleton;
  
  private constructor() {}

  public getInstance() {
    if (!this.instance) { 
      this.instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return this.instance;
  }
}
```

I realized it's pretty useless in case you want some other class to be a singleton too. It's not extendable. You have to write that singleton stuff for every class you want to be a singleton.

Decorators for the rescue.

```js
@singleton
class MyClassThatIsSingletonToo {}
```

You can write decorator by yourself or take some from npm. I found [this](https://github.com/aigoncharov/singleton/blob/master/index.ts) proxy-based implementation from [@keenondrums/singleton](https://github.com/aigoncharov/singleton) package neat enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * The Singleton class defines the `getInstance` method that lets clients access
 * the unique singleton instance.
 */
class Singleton {
    private static instance: Singleton;

    /**
     * The Singleton's constructor should always be private to prevent direct
     * construction calls with the `new` operator.
     */
    private constructor() { }

    /**
     * The static method that controls the access to the singleton instance.
     *
     * This implementation let you subclass the Singleton class while keeping
     * just one instance of each subclass around.
     */
    public static getInstance(): Singleton {
        if (!Singleton.instance) {
            Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
        }

        return Singleton.instance;
    }

    /**
     * Finally, any singleton should define some business logic, which can be
     * executed on its instance.
     */
    public someBusinessLogic() {
        // ...
    }
}

/**
 * The client code.
 */
function clientCode() {
    const s1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    const s2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    if (s1 === s2) {
        console.log('Singleton works, both variables contain the same instance.');
    } else {
        console.log('Singleton failed, variables contain different instances.');
    }
}

clientCode();
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from all the others that provide a getInstance() method for lazy initialization?

Comment: It has better explanation of each step of the code.
And why does it matter if I added another answer that has overlap in the solution?

Comment: I agree that yours is nicely formatted and commented. But it matters, because this question already has 23 answers and new ones are coming in monthly. Instead of duplicating existing answers, it would be best to comment on already existing ones to clarify them or ask questions. Or edit existing answers if they can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the longest process to make a singleton in typescript, but in larger applications is the one that has worked better for me.

First you need a Singleton class in, let's say, *"./utils/Singleton.ts"*:

```
module utils {
    export class Singleton {
        private _initialized: boolean;

        private _setSingleton(): void {
            if (this._initialized) throw Error('Singleton is already initialized.');
            this._initialized = true;
        }

        get setSingleton() { return this._setSingleton; }
    }
}
```

Now imagine you need a Router singleton *"./navigation/Router.ts"*:

```
/// <reference path="../utils/Singleton.ts" />

module navigation {
    class RouterClass extends utils.Singleton {
        // NOTICE RouterClass extends from utils.Singleton
        // and that it isn't exportable.

        private _init(): void {
            // This method will be your "construtor" now,
            // to avoid double initialization, don't forget
            // the parent class setSingleton method!.
            this.setSingleton();

            // Initialization stuff.
        }

        // Expose _init method.
        get init { return this.init; }
    }

    // THIS IS IT!! Export a new RouterClass, that no
    // one can instantiate ever again!.
    export var Router: RouterClass = new RouterClass();
}
```

Nice!, now initialize or import wherever you need:

```
/// <reference path="./navigation/Router.ts" />

import router = navigation.Router;

router.init();
router.init(); // Throws error!.
```

The nice thing about doing singletons this way is that you still use all the beauty of typescript classes, it gives you nice intellisense, the singleton logic keeps someway separated and it's easy to remove if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Symbols in your module. This way you can protect your class, also if the final user of your API is using normal Javascript:

```
let _instance = Symbol();
export default class Singleton {

    constructor(singletonToken) {
        if (singletonToken !== _instance) {
            throw new Error("Cannot instantiate directly.");
        }
        //Init your class
    }

    static get instance() {
        return this[_instance] || (this[_instance] = new Singleton(_singleton))
    }

    public myMethod():string {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var str:string = Singleton.instance.myFoo();
```

If the user is using your compiled API js file, also will get an error if he try to instantiate manually your class:

```
// PLAIN JAVASCRIPT: 
var instance = new Singleton(); //Error the argument singletonToken !== _instance symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript, one doesn't necessarily have to follow the `new instance()` Singleton methodology. An imported, constructor-less static class can work equally as well.

Consider:

```
export class YourSingleton {

   public static foo:bar;

   public static initialise(_initVars:any):void {
     YourSingleton.foo = _initvars.foo;
   }

   public static doThing():bar {
     return YourSingleton.foo
   }
}
```

You can import the class and refer to `YourSingleton.doThing()` in any other class. But remember, because this is a static class, it has no constructor so I usually use an `intialise()` method that is called from a class that imports the Singleton:

```
import {YourSingleton} from 'singleton.ts';

YourSingleton.initialise(params);
let _result:bar = YourSingleton.doThing();
```

Don't forget that in a static class, every method and variable needs to also be static so instead of `this` you would use the full class name `YourSingleton`.

Answer (score 1):

After scouring this thread and playing around with all the options above - I settled with a Singleton that can be created with proper constructors:

```
export default class Singleton {
  private static _instance: Singleton

  public static get instance(): Singleton {
    return Singleton._instance
  }

  constructor(...args: string[]) {
    // Initial setup

    Singleton._instance = this
  }

  work() { /* example */ }

}
```

It would require an initial setup (in `main.ts`, or `index.ts`), which can easily be implemented by
`new Singleton(/* PARAMS */)`

Then, anywhere in your code, just call `Singleton.instnace`; in this case, to get `work` done, I would call `Singleton.instance.work()`

Comment: Why would someone downvote an answer without actually commenting on improvements? We're a *community*

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way to do it with a more conventional javascript approach using an [IFFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
module App.Counter {
    export var Instance = (() => {
        var i = 0;
        return {
            increment: (): void => {
                i++;
            },
            getCount: (): number => {
                return i;
            }
        }
    })();
}

module App {
    export function countStuff() {
        App.Counter.Instance.increment();
        App.Counter.Instance.increment();
        alert(App.Counter.Instance.getCount());
    }
}

App.countStuff();
```

View a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYQwyd?editors=001)

Comment: What is the reason to add the `Instance` variable? You coukd simply put the variable and the functions directly under `App.Counter`.

Comment: @fyaa Yes you could but the variable and the functions directly under App.Counter but I think this approach conforms better to the singleton pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pure singleton (initialization may be not lazy), but similar pattern with help of `namespace`s.

```
namespace MyClass
{
    class _MyClass
    {
    ...
    }
    export const instance: _MyClass = new _MyClass();
}
```

Access to object of Singleton:

```
MyClass.instance
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way

```
class YourSingletoneClass {
  private static instance: YourSingletoneClass;

  private constructor(public ifYouHaveAnyParams: string) {

  }
  static getInstance() {
    if(!YourSingletoneClass.instance) {
      YourSingletoneClass.instance = new YourSingletoneClass('If you have any params');
    }
    return YourSingletoneClass.instance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets go by an example, I want to create singleton class by which I will able to create a connection of a client then I want to use that same connected client everywhere.

```
import nats, { Stan } from 'node-nats-streaming';

class NatsWrapper {
  private _client?: Stan;

  get client() {
    if (!this._client) {
      throw new Error('Cannot access NATS client before connecting');
    }
    return this._client;
  }

  connect(clusterId: string, clientId: string, url: string) {
    this._client = nats.connect(clusterId, clientId, { url });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.on('connect', (result) => {
        console.log('Connected to NATS');
        resolve(result);
      });
      this.client.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
}

// since we create and export the instace, it will act like a singleton
export const natsWrapper = new NatsWrapper();
```

Now, first create the conneciton in your index.ts/app.ts file then you will be able to access the same client just by importing anywhere

index.ts

```
    await natsWrapper.connect(
      'ticketing',
      'client_id_random_str',
      'http://nats-srv:4222'
    );
```

someFile.ts

```
import { natsWrapper } from '../nats-wrapper';

const abc = () =>{
    console.log(natsWrapper.client)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled to find a proper solution for declaring singleton pattern class in typescript.

I think below is more practical solution.

```
class MySingletonClass {
    public now:Date = new Date();
    public arg:string;
    constructor(arg:string) {
        this.arg = arg;

        // Make singleton
        if ('instance' in MySingletonClass) return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MySingletonClass, 'instance')?.value;
        Object.assign(MySingletonClass, { instance: this });
    }
}

const a = new MySingletonClass('a');
console.log(a);

const b = new MySingletonClass('b');
console.log(b);

console.log('a === b', a === b);
console.log('a.now === b.now', a.now === b.now);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Singleton<CREATOR extends () => any>
{
  private m_fnGetInstance: () => ReturnType<CREATOR>;
  public get Instance() { return this.m_fnGetInstance(); }
  public constructor(creator: CREATOR) {
    this.m_fnGetInstance = () => {
      const instance = creator();
      this.m_fnGetInstance = () => instance;
      return instance;
    };
  }
}

const Foo = new Singleton(() => new class {
  public bar() {}
});

Foo.Instance.bar();
```

It is fast because there is no conditional branching.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCWA7A5iApgFwPaIDwGEAlAUQEEAVAeUOjQA8M1EATGACgEpoBeAPmjCIAnrwCwAKADeE6NAAOAJ3gA3MI2gBbAPoAzRAHFMASUQQMg4GgBc0Tj36FMAVwWJyQuWgIkK1XgG4ZeScAIxB4YGhkTGgTMws0O0loBWdXaAwAC3gIADptPUMMOPNES05-aABfILlQ8MjgHDMFJ2BsBTZgVLUsBRsiMipCLmlxWVksnPzdA2NTUsseWy4+aDGJiaaF6CR4srRl7rRezo5A8c2M7LyCueKFhOW7Nb3FtAurlLTEXceDz4TKqAmriUESbZmOBIVCYHAAOTQAHdlohkdCUOhsIg2C9+GiUaBIDANsEwhFoDosFgkqCqucJBDmhgMgAGZaeBRUhQaBK5RBYJEVCTcthY3bLVmVeDQXDQACMrKVyqV0oA1GqOKSEJi4YhEUjciU+VSaQywUydhh5Ry0Fy+ryDvzBcLxJCsOhciAsMg2AADA3QGwAEkk1ugAFo2VUNBA-ebGW7wFAMbDsQAZNDIMDAIQSUmKFRqQ7xDAUiDGg4AfhsOrTOEz2dzyycLDQOiQaGYgLq5MipYp0RZlfKo2gQVk8B0bDrWIbWZzQlyFf+li4qQwLl+s71jcXy5HHwnqbniD3uYPq8O3GgBJPu4Xuddmw3W-vGcfS5X+0slSCoNkXsGkpalaQkcE3WZDIACZbXtHk+QFIVzVFcUZRvKUJTlRUVWVdVNW1GFT3PJdD1yU1XVBSEWQwABmODuUdSxnWQi53U9b1fT9Eig2gUM6MjGCYzjc0gA)

[github](https://github.com/CODIANZ/npm.singleton)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code as well:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class SingletonDemo {
  private static _instance: SingletonDemo;

  public static getInstance() {
    return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
  }

  public static resetInstance() {
    this._instance = null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Template One

```
class Singleton {
        
        /**
         * private : Making instance private ensuring that it can only be accessed with Singleton class itself.
         * static : Making instance static means it belongs to class itself rather than instances of the classes.  This ensures that there is only one instance of "instance" shared across all instances of the class
         */
        private static instance: Singleton;
    
        /**
         * private : Making the constructor "private" prevents instantiation of the class from outside.
         */
        private constructor() {}
    
    
        public static getInstance(): Singleton {
            if(!Singleton.instance){
                Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return Singleton.instance;
        }
    }
```

Template Two (Early Loading)

```
class DatabaseConnection{
    private static instance = new DatabaseConnection();
    private constructor() {};
    public static getInstance(): DatabaseConnection {
        return DatabaseConnection.instance;
    }
}
```

Template Three

```
class DatabaseConnection{
    private static instance : DatabaseConnection;
    private constructor(){};
    public static getInstance(): DatabaseConnection{
        if(!DatabaseConnection.instance){
            DatabaseConnection.instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        }
        return DatabaseConnection.instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace MySingleton {
  interface IMySingleton {
      doSomething(): void;
  }
  class MySingleton implements IMySingleton {
      private usePrivate() { }
      doSomething() {
          this.usePrivate();
      }
  }
  export var Instance: IMySingleton = new MySingleton();
}
```

This way we can apply an interface, unlike in Ryan Cavanaugh's accepted answer.