# Typescript: Static methods unable to access private properties in constructor

Tags: typescript, constructor, this, static-methods

Trying to make a static function give access to a property xdate, which was initialized in the constructor (in typescript 1.5.3).

this.xdate is accessible in all other instance methods.
it remains inaccessible in the static method.

Q. Is there anyway I can make this.xdate accessible in the static method?

Below is my code:-

```
class vehicle{
  constructor(private xdate = new Date()){}

  vroom(){    console.log(this.xdate);  }
  static staticvroom(){ console.log(this.xdate);} //Warning: Property 'xdate' does not exist on type 'typeof vehicle'.


}//vehicle ends

let v1 = new vehicle;
v1.vroom(); //works

vehicle.staticvroom(); //undefined

/* this is how i executed it:- 
D:\js\Ang2\proj2\myforms\tsc_cRAP>tsc 7_.ts
7_.ts(18,42): error TS2339: Property 'xdate' does not exist on type 'typeof vehicle'.

D:\js\Ang2\proj2\myforms\tsc_cRAP>node 7_.js
2017-06-23T09:17:41.365Z
undefined

*/
```

Any pointers would be of great help.
(If this is a repeated question, apologies in advance)

/*
UglyHack#1: since static methods are available even before the instance of an object, I created a tmp obj. within staticvroom(){} and it worked.

```
static staticvroom(){ 
  console.log((new vehicle).xdate); 
}
```

Not sure the performance issues on this.

*/

Comment: You cannot. Since `this` inside static members refers to the class itself instead of the class instance.

Comment: I can create a new obj. within the static method and then access it using the obj variable. this worked for me: `  static staticvroom(){
    let x = new vehicle;
    console.log(x.xdate);  }  `

Comment: That's a horrible design, and it's **extremely** error prone.

Comment: Can you explain why is it horrible? I can set the object to null and delete all references to it towards the end in staticvroom(). static methods are accessible even before an instance is created; just might use that functionality, i thought. though i know its ugly, but i dont see any performance issues.

Comment: Static methods can not access any non-static parts of that class' instances by design. It seems like you should either not have that method static or not have `xdate` as a non-static field. However, we cannot be sure of this unless you improve your question with your main intents.

Comment: If you need an instance for an operation then don't use static (unless it's the singleton pattern). It's that simple.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: so creating an object of the class within the same class doesnt seem to be that horrible. looks to me like i should NOT create the new vehicle() within staticvroom() but within a static member; that seems like its ok. maybe doing it like a singleton pattern looks worthwhile, like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154320/4337871

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, based on your code all you need to do is get a date, and for that, it makes no sense to do all of what you're doing now. I assume that you have a different case in your real problem. Maybe if you explain better what is your problem you'll be able to get better help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass instance as parameter

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor(private xdate = new Date()) {}
  vroom(){
    console.log(this.xdate);
  }
  static staticVar: Date = new Date();
  static staticvroom(vehicle: Vehicle) {
    console.log(vehicle.xdate);
    console.log(this.staticVar); // You can even access static vars with this
  }


}// vehicle ends

let v1 = new Vehicle;
v1.vroom(); // works

Vehicle.staticvroom(v1);
```