# Conditional Angular Component Provider

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a component that depends on a service that may either be provided by its parent component or create a new instance of that service depending on a dynamic condition.

The problem I have is that if I specify a provider, or even a service provider, I lose the parent instance of the service. Is it possible to get a handle on the parent instance?

```
 providers: [ myserviceProvider]
```

pseudo code in myServiceProvider:

```
provide: MyService,
    useFactory: myServiceFactory,
    deps: [AuthorisationService]

const myServiceFactory = (authorisationService: AuthorisationService) => {
  return authorisationService.isAuthorised() ? /** what goes here? *// : new MyService();
};
```

In the /* what goes here? */  space I want to return the existing  instance of myservice which would be injected if I hadn't declared a provider

edited for clarity:
the parent instance wouldn't be the root instance of the service (it has its own provider as well which is just injecting using standard provider syntax)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for here is a basic Singleton, if I'm not mistaking?

See the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174078/how-to-define-singleton-in-typescript) on how to create one

Comment: no not a singleton, I need either the parent instance or a new instance depending on a condition that's multiple possible instances