# getting parent context of a class in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have 2 classes (in reality one base class and many others).
I would like to get the parent context in child class without having to populate back `super()`every time. The base aim of that it to split my angular component into multiple classes. I will try make an example

```
//export.ts
export * from './parent'
export * from './child'

//parent.ts

import {fabric} from 'fabric'
import {Child} from './child'

export class Parent {
    //many other variables here
    canvas:fabric.Canvas = undefined;
    childTest:Child      = undefined;
    width:number         = undefined;
    height:number        = undefined;
    //many other variables here too

    constructor(){

    }

    initCanvas(canvasId:string, options:fabric.ICanvasOptions){
        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasId, options);
        //here canvas is populated
        this.childTest = new Child('this is only a test')
    }
}

//child.ts

import { Parent } from './export'
import {fabric} from 'fabric'

export class Child extends Parent {

    constructor(test:string){
      super();
      let rect = new fabric.Rect([0,0, 10, 10], {
        //lots of options here
      })
      this.canvas.add(rect) // returns canvas is undefined
    }
}
// something.component.ts
  import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, ElementRef, Inject} from '@angular/core';
  import { Parent } from '../class/export'
  //some code
  parent:Parent     = undefined
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.parent = new Parent();
    this.parent.initCanvas('myCanvas', {
      //a lot of options
    })
  }
```

so as you can see I cannot retrieve `this.canvas` and work with it is there any workarounds. I know I could pass the canvas into the method but I would prefer just like in a component to use the `this`keyword to access a global context.

so basically what I would like to do is:

```
call ngAfterViewInit()
     |_ call Parent()
     |_ call Parent.initCanvas() from parent and instanciate the canvas variable
         |_ call Child() and retrieve the upper canvas variable instantiated
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you set `canvas:fabric.Canvas = undefined;` so offcourse it will be undefined until you don'tcall `initCanvas` method in your parent class

Comment: sorry I've forgot to add the component. thanks for the comment

Comment: @jitender done the changes

Comment: So you are calling `this.parent.initCanvas` from some something component and you want `this.canvas` to not be `undefined` in your child class?

Comment: @jitender I want a global context. I init a Parent class with all the main variables then access some variables in the child classes. I don't see why instantiating the class inside a component should be a problem. Many thanks in advance

Comment: i think instead of inheritence you are looking for [Singleton pattren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30174360/5621827)

Comment: @jitender interesting many thanks I will try that and if it works you could write an answer. I won't try it now bu t thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Angular service that holds the canvas. 
You got two options
1. Add methods on the service like:

```
yourCanvasService.addStuffThatUsedToBeInChild1(..). 

yourCanvasService.addStuffThatUsedToBeInChild2(..).
```

2. Keep the old Child classes but don let them extend Parent. Instead inject the Angular Service in the classes constuctor and THEN use the service more common methods.

   ```
   export class ARectangleClass{
       constuctor(private theService:MyCanvasService){
           theService.addShape();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: If you would get any problems with keeping the actual canvas int the service, then just store a model in the service so the canvas can paint itself from it

Answer (score 2):

```
export class Parent {
    protected canvas:fabric.Canvas;
    constructor(){}

    protected initCanvas(canvasId:string, options:fabric.ICanvasOptions){
        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasId, options);
        //here canvas is populated
        this.childTest = new Child('this is only a test')
    }
}
```

And the child

```
export class Child extends Parent {

    constructor(test:string){
      super();

    }

    init(canvasId,options){
      this.initCanvas(canvasId);
      let rect = new fabric.Rect([0,0, 10, 10], options)
      this.canvas.add(rect) 
    }

}
```

and in Component

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.child= new Child();
    this.child.init('myCanvas', {
      //a lot of options
    })
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer .Sorry but I really don't understand the logic. I've done class to avoid setting everything in the component. in your example I'm doing everything back as it was before. there must be a way to create a global context and split component into different files and keeping the context

Comment: Ok sorry I just changed the code so it made use of the  parent class In standard way. And with my changes, canvas would be set. Is it the canvas you would like to be global?

Comment: Ok sorry I must explain myself badly. The main Idea is for example. When I use the `this` keyword on a component I have access to it in all the functions. Now I want to split my component into classes and use the `this` of my base class into my child. So if my `this.canvas` is instantiated in my parent I would like to use it into my child class, just as I would use a `canvas` global variable into my component. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Yes in my example you need to call  this.initCanvas specific in the childs ngAfterViewInit. You would like to avoid that? I Think a know away if that is the issue

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() is not a child it's upper. call order is (ngAfterViewInit(Parent(Child()))) where the context of parent is retrieved in the child with an instantiated canvas

Comment: Yes but in that case I need to update my values from the child Class and this is not what I would like to do. Sounds logic don't you think so? there will be many child classes I cannot update on each and one of them. stil I upvot for the effort . Can we continue on chat maybe you will have better understanding. thanks

Comment: Sorry cant chat now. What values would you like to update for all of the children? It is the options for the canvas? I my example code the options for the canvas is not set in the child.init. its always set in the parent. In one place

Comment: I need to have hierachical and logic order I set canvas global and then use it in child. Imagine I have 3 childs, I'm not going to initialize on 3 childs or on last child my canvas and then move it to 4 fourth one if I add another one.

Comment: If you would set the canvas global and reuse it all the time it would share all the childrens grafic. If child1 added a rectangle it would be in the canvas for child2.  If this is what you want you could use a angular service

Comment: Is there any other ways to do that without a service?

Comment: If the canvas always have the same id and options and any grafic you add to it should stay on it, there no reason to create childrens. Because childrens mean that they should differ, I guess. The service is the singleton of Angular so I would use that.

Comment: I appreciate your advice but still How can I split my service and keep the same context. see the problem?

Comment: Could you just have different methods for adding the stuff to the global canvas? yourCanvasService.addStuffThatUsedToBeInChild1(..). yourCanvasService.addStuffThatUsedToBeInChild2(..).

Comment: can you add this as an answer I'll make it answered. Thanks