# Jest with node and TypeScript - checking throw error from static method in Singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a following problem. I have a singleton class. There is a getInstance static method which call constructor.
singleton.ts:

```
class Singleton {
   private static singletonInstance: Singleton;
   private constructor(){
      ...doSomething;
   }
   public static getInstance(): Singleton {
      if(!Singleton.singletonInstance){
          Singleton.singletonInstance = new Singleton();
      }
      throw new Error('stupid error');
   }
}
```

singleton.spec.ts:

```
it('getInstance should throw an error', () => {
   expect(Singleton.getInstance()).toThrow(new Error('stupid error'));
})
```

'getInstance should throw an error' is failing, because... getInstance() didn't throw the error.

On console output I can notice the error was throw - it prints 'stupid error'.

Comment: I think you should verify the singleton creation. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36978360/6161531

Comment: Jeppe, thank you for your comment. It is just example. Of course my singleton class check if instance already exist. I updated my example code for not confusing another users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the example mentioned in the docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror), you need to supply an anonymous function to test this:

```
it('getInstance should throw an error', () => {
   expect(() => Singleton.getInstance()).toThrow(new Error('stupid error'));
})
```

Basically, jest calls the given function, and then determines whether it threw an error or not. In your case, since `Singleton.getInstance()` has already thrown the error, the result is not callable.

Comment: Thanks mate! You made my day. I couldn't handle this.