# Is there a way to implement a Singleton class in Typescript using ECMAScript private fields?

Tags: typescript

Related to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174078/how-to-define-singleton-in-typescript) that has a useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36978360/6609345) using Typescript private fields: It has the drawback that those fields become public fields in plain Javascript and there is a loss in protecting instantiation.

With Typescript 2.8 [ECMAScript private fields support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#ecmascript-private-fields) I was wondering if one could come up with another solution.

Comment: Javascript hasn't  access modifier like java or typescript. You have to use function-style object modeling if you want some kind of protection.

Comment: TC 39 [proposal on class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/) (which is stage 3 at the moment) includes a syntax to make a class field private (using `#`)